# Building a cross-architecture application (using Rust)

Tags: cross-platform, rust

I started to learn Rust programming language and I use Linux. I'd like to build a cross-platform application using this language.

The question might not be related to Rust language in particular, but nonetheless, how do I do that? I'm interested in building a "Hello World" cross-platform application as well as for more complicated ones. I just need to get the idea.

So what do I do?

**UPDATE**:

What I want to do is the ability to run a program on 3 different platforms without changing the **sources**. Do I have to build a new binary file for each platform from the sources? Just like I could do in C

Comment: Could you clarify your question? Because a cross platform hello world is: `fn main() { println("Hello world!"); }` (Do you want information about actually compiling and distributing binaries on different platforms?)

Comment: @dbaupp I want to be able to launch "Hello World" on all 3-4 main os. Once compile -- run everywhere.

Comment: Ah, so you want a single binary that runs on all platforms?

Comment: Aha, well, Rust is a compiled language like C or Go: it creates native executables, which are specific to each OS; not like Java where it compiles to bytecode targeting the JVM. So, at the very least, you have to compile a binary for each platform.

Comment: @dbaupp I'm not familiar with cross-platform development. What I want to do is the ability to run a program on 3 different platforms without changing its sources. Do I have to build a new binary file for each platform from the sources? Just like I could do in C.

Comment: Since this question is specific to the architecture and not the platform, i'm going to fix the title. The platform would be windows/osx.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The best way to figure this out is to download the source code for [Servo](https://github.com/mozilla/servo) and explore it on your own. Servo is absolutely a cross-platform codebase, so it will have to address all of these questions, whether they be answered in build/configuration files, or the Rust source itself.

Answer (score 20):

To run on multiple platforms you need to build an executable for each as @huon-dbauapp commented.

This is fairly straightforward with Rust. You use "--target=" with rustc to tell it what you want to build. The same flag works with Cargo.

For example, this builds for an ARM target:

`cargo build --target=arm-unknown-linux-gnueabihf`

See the Rust [Flexible Target Specification](https://github.com/rust-lang/rfcs/blob/master/text/0131-target-specification.md) for more about targets.

However, Rust doesn't ship with the std Crate compiled for ARM (as of June 2015). If this is the case for your target, you'll first need to compile the std Crates for the target yourself, which involves compiling the Rust compiler from source, and specifying the target for that build!

For information, most of this is copied from: https://github.com/japaric/ruststrap/blob/master/1-how-to-cross-compile.md

The following instructions are for gcc, so if you don't have this you'll need to install it. You'll also need the corresponding cross compiler tools, so for gcc:

`sudo apt-get install gcc-arm-linux-gnueabihf`

### Compile Rust std Crate For ARM

The following example assumes you've already installed the current Rust Nightly, so we'll just get the sources and compile for ARM. If you are using a different version of the compiler, you'll need to get that to ensure your ARM libraries match the version of the compiler you're using to build your projects.

```
mkdir ~/toolchains
cd ~/toolchains
git clone https://github.com/rust-lang/rust.git
cd rust
git update
```

Build rustc for ARM

```
cd ~/toolchains/rust
./configure --target=arm-unknown-linux-gnueabihf,x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu
make -j4
sudo make install
```

Note "-j4" needs at least 8GB RAM, so if you hit a problem above try "make" instead.

### Install ARM rustc libraries In native rustc build

```
sudo ln -s $HOME/src/rust/arm-unknown-linux-gnueabihf /usr/lib/rustlib/arm-unknown-linux-gnueabihf
```

Create hello.rs containing:

```
pub fn main() {
    println!("Hello, world!");
}
```

Compile hello.rs, and tell rustc the name of the cross-compiler (which must be in your PATH):

`rustc -C linker=arm-linux-gnueabihf-gcc-4.9 --target=arm-unknown-linux-gnueabihf hello.rs`

Check that the produced binary is really an ARM binary:
`$ file hello`
hello: ELF 32-bit LSB  shared object, ARM, EABI5 version 1 (SYSV), (..)

SUCCESS!!!:

### Check: the binary should work on an ARM device

```
$ scp hello me@arm:~
$ ssh me@arm ./hello

Hello, world!
```

I've used this to build and link a Rust project with a separate C library as well. Instructions similar to the above on how to do this, dynamically or statically are in a separate post, but I've used my link quota up already!

Answer (score 3):

It looks like the rust compiler might not be ready to build standalone binaries for windows yet (see the windows section [here](https://github.com/mozilla/rust/wiki/Note-getting-started-developing-Rust)), so this probably can't be done yet.

For posix systems it should mostly Just Work unless you're trying to do GUI stuff.

Answer (score 3):

Yes, you won't need to change the source, unless you are using specific libraries that are not cross-platform.

But as @dbaupp said native executables are different on each platform, *nix uses ELF, Windows  PE, and OSX Mach-O. So you will need to compile it for each platform.

I don't know the state of cross-compiling in rust, but if they already implemented it, then you should be able to build all the binaries in the same platform, if not, you will have to build each binary on it's platform.